# Помогите с упрощением кода новичку, пожалуйста! Python/Питон

Tags: python

Как можно упростить этот код? Просто понимаю, что он (а именно последняя строчка) какой-то некрасивый и длинный. Цель кода в том, чтобы перемножить элементы одного списка на элементы другого соответственно их порядковому номеру (0 элемнт на 0 элемент, 1 на 1, 2 на 2 и т.д.)

```
d = [12, 5, 2, 14, 9]
sh = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
list1=list(zip(d,sh)) 
#Так я объеденил списки, сделав кортежи в списке: list1 = [(12, 1), (5, 2), (2, 3), (14, 4), (9, 5)]

#Сейчас буду делать функцию для умножения всех элементов списка
from functools import reduce
import operator
def prod(iterable):
    return reduce(operator.mul, iterable, 1)

print(list(prod(list1[0]),prod(list1[1]), prod(list1[2]), prod(list1[3]), prod(list1[4])))

Результат: [12, 10, 6, 56, 45]
```

Код работаетет, но мне не нравится его вид. Так много `prod` из-за того, что `map` почему-то не хотела работать с `prod`:

```
print(list(map(prod, (list1[0]), (list1[1]), (list1[2]), (list1[3]), (list1[4]))))

TypeError: prod() takes 1 positional argument but 5 were given
```

Как сдалать правильно? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так попробуйте:

```
 [a*b for a,b in zip(d,sh)]
```

Answer (score 1):

2 варианта:

без map:

```
print(*[prod(i) for i in list1])
```

c map:

```
print(*map(prod, list1))
```